# Is there a way to enable "KEEP_SIMPLE_BLOCKS_IN_ONE_LINE" CodeStyle option in IntelliJ for kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, coding-style

I am searching for a way to customize my code style settings in IntelliJ / Android Studio (current version 3.2.1). The problem is, I am missing the KEEP_SIMPLE_BLOCKS_IN_ONE_LINE Option for kotlin ( the same option is available for java).

Is there a way to enable this option for kotlin? For example by coding a plugin for IntelliJ or changing some IDE configs? And if so, where should I start? Has someone of you done something similar?

Comment: You can send a pull request adding this option to the Kotlin plugin. The code of the formatter is [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/idea/formatter/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea).

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I needed